# Access Jaas.conf file from HDFS in Java action in Oozie workflow

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

My program gets connected to hive using kerberos authentication and get query result from hive.

Workflow directory(HDFS):

```
| lib/javaCode.jar
| workflow.xml
| jaas.conf
| job.properties
```

My Java Action in workflow.xml

```
<action name="run_java_script" cred="hcat_creds">
        <java>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <main-class>GetData</main-class>
            <arg>${filepath}</arg>
            <arg>${url}</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="end" />
</action>
```

My Job.properties file is correct.

Jaas.conf

```
com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   useTicketCache=true
   principal="host@EXAMPLE.COM"
   doNotPrompt=true
   keyTab="path_to_keytab/hos.keytab"
   debug=true;
};
```

GetData.java

```
public class GetData  extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new GetData(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String jaas_file = args[0];
        String url_connect = args[1];
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");

        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", jaas_file);
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

        System.out.println("getting connection");
        String JDBC_DB_URL = url_connect;
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_DB_URL);
        System.out.println("got connection");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println(execute(con, "show databases"));
        con.close();

        return 0;
    }

    public static String execute(Connection connection, String query) throws SQLException {
        // Code to execute    
    }
}
```

Oozie workflow stdout:

```
>>> Invoking Main class now >>>

Fetching child yarn jobs
tag id : oozie-TagID
Child yarn jobs are found - 
Main class        : GetData
Arguments         :
                    jaas.conf
                    URL

getting connection

<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<
```

I don't get any result coz my Jaas.conf should be available in FileSystem not on HDFS. My program works perfectly good when Jass.conf is on FileSystem. Is there any possible way to access jaas.conf from HDFS instead of copying it to my File system?

Comment: **1.** please make up your mind whether the file is named JAAS (as expected) or JASS, JSSA, JSAS, whatever **2.** please note than since Java 1.6 the default JAAS entry is `com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate` cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/jgss-features.html release notes **3.** more to the point, please learn about the Oozie `<file>` instruction, cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031028/oozie-shell-action-exec-and-file-tags/35048788#35048788

Comment: Thanks.. Point 3 resolved my issue.. Thanks..